# Why is my Rails method always being called on save (without an after_save callback set)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails model I have a series of hard-coded questions (loaded into the DB using YAML). In order to display these to the user I have a SaleQualifier model - this `has_many questions` and `has_one answer`.

In the SalesOpportunity show action (where the SaleQualifier will be displayed from). I create a new SaleQualifier and build the associated question:

```
def show
 @sales_opportunity = SalesOpportunity.includes(:company, :user, :timeline_events, :sale_contacts, :swots, :sale_competitors).find(params[:id])
 @sale_qualifier = SaleQualifier.new(sales_opportunity_id: params[@sales_opportunity.id])
 @answer = @sale_qualifier.answers.build
#if the question_id is blank it is the first question in the list
 if @sale_qualifier.question_id.blank?
  @question = Question.find_by_id(@sale_qualifier.next_question_id)
 else
  @question = Question.find_by_id(@sale_qualifier.question_id)
 end
end
```

The Answer model is set up to ensure that once it becomes saved and permanently tied to this SaleQualifier it will fire an `after_save` callback to update the SaleQualifier (adding a `has_answer` tag, finding the appropriate `next_question_id` etc).

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :answer_text, presence: true
 belongs_to :sale_qualifier
 after_save :update_sale_qualifier

 def update_sale_qualifier
  sale_qualifier.update_next_question
  sale_qualifier.save
 end
end
```

The `sale_qualifier.save` line is what is causing me the problem. Rather than purely saving the record, it saves the record AND calls the update_next_question action again. I don't know why, as there's no after_save callback in my SaleQualifier model:

```
class SaleQualifier < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :answer, :inverse_of => :sale_qualifier, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer
 belongs_to :sales_opportunity
 validates :sales_opportunity_id, presence: true

def update_next_question
   #find the question that this SaleQualifier is associated with
   question = Question.find_by_id(self.question_id)
   #get its answer_type as this defines whether we need to look at the next_question_id_no or not
   ans_type = question.answer_type
   if ans_type == 'Text Field' || ans_type == 'Datetime' || ans_type == 'Integer' || ans_type == 'Boolean' && self.answer.answer_text == 'True'
    self.next_question_id = question.next_question_id_yes
    #if the answer_type is a boolean and the answer is no/false, then use the next_question_id_no to route the question
elsif ans_type == 'Boolean' && self.answer.answer_text == 'False'
    self.next_question_id = question.next_question_id_no
   end
   #mark the question as answered, in case we need to iterate over the same quesiton in future
   self.has_answer = true
   #create a new SaleQualifier with the question set as the next question, unless it already exists and hasn't been answered yet or unless the next question id leads us to a result (i.e. no questions left in the tree)
   SaleQualifier.create(question_id: self.next_question_id, sales_opportunity_id: self.sales_opportunity_id) unless Question.exists?(:id => self.next_question_id) || SaleQualifier.find_by(question_id: self.next_question_id) && SaleQualifier.find_by(question_id: self.next_question_id).has_answer == false
 end
end
```

Can anyone tell me why the `update_next_question` method is calling itself in a loop every time I save my SaleQualifier?

Comment: Try removing `sale_qualifier.save` from the answer and putting a save at the end of `update_next_question` (note: this is a fishing expedition, I don't know that doing this will solve anything, but it might be interesting/useful to see what happens)

Comment: Also: how do you currently know that update_next_question is being called twice? (ie what information are you not sharing with us about what you've tried and what the results are)? :)

Comment: Finally: when debugging some complicated code that you're not sure where the error is... I find it useful to strip out all the complicated bits then add bits back in until you can see the problem recurring... the line you just added is the one causing the bug. In this case... empty our `update_next_question` eg put a comment before every line... then slowly uncomment lines one at a time until you see the bug again.

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast - I used Byebug to step through the solution, so I can see that the update_next_question model is fully executed before the program skips back to the sale_qualifier.save line. As soon as that is called I jump straight back to the question = Question.find_by_id(self.question_id) line. I've also tried saving a model using the console (not the development server) and the error still manifests itself. I have tried your first suggestion too, calling self.save at the end of my update_next_question and that also results in the endless loop.

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer` could plausibly be the issue - if your sale_qualifier contains an answer... then when you try to save it, it might go back into saving the associated answer... which calls the after_save hook.  Definitely try it with completely empty methods, try it in the console but calling a fresh, new answer, pull out an existing SaleQualifier and try to manually call update_next_question... ie try as many different ways of triggering the bug as you can to get more info.

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast - I quickly changed the after_save callback on the Answer model to an after_create callback, and that has solved the problem. If you want to post that as the answer then I'll accept it as the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we figured out that there's a one-time feedback loop involved by the fact that `Answer` calls `save` on a `SaleQualifer` and `SaleQualifier` contains `accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer`.... so if you have a `SaleQualifer` that contains attributes for an `Answer` then you save the answer, it will use the `after_save` callback, then call save, which saves the `SaleQualifer`, which calls save on the `answer`... which calls the `after_save` callback again.

So yeah, changing that to an after_create hook fixes it by breaking the cycle on the `sale_qualifier.save` line.